# How to render Datatable column to display json beautifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to display json response in proper format inside DataTable. But when I have checked I have understood that DataTable doesn't access this "\n" for line change. So I have figured out tis library which can help me to do so: [library_url](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/pretty-print-json.html)

Now  how can i add render my feed column so that I can display that column in proper format. Here is my DataTable Code:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable( {
          serverSide: true,
          processing: true,
          "paging": true,
          dom: "ltip",
          "searching": { "regex": true },
          "pageLength": 10,
          "ajax": function(data, callback, settings) {
              $.get(base_url + 'ajax/get-sensor-feeds.php', {
                  sensor: app_type,
                  app: app,
                  limit: data.length,
                  offset: data.start
                  }, function(res) {
                     var json = JSON.parse(res);
                     $('.loadingDiv').hide();
                      callback({
                          recordsTotal: json.count,
                          recordsFiltered: json.count,
                          data: json.results
                      });
                });
          },
          "columns": [
            { "data": "id" , width: '7%'},
            { "data": "feed", width: '78%'},
            { "data": "created_at", width: '15%'},
          ]
        });
```

I have tried adding the below following code but I was getting the error.

```
{ "render" : function(data, type, row) {
              if(data == "feed") {
                console.log("reached");
                return prettyPrintJson.toHtml(data);
              }
            }}
```

I am getting an error :

> Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I am getting an error ` Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`. The thing is I am not thinking its going even inside if statment

Comment: The error is not occuring in the provided code sample then. There's no attempt access to the style property anywhere

Comment: Then how to do sorting then

Comment: That's a different question ‍♂️ 
But you can check [here](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) or how i would do it using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/)